# Ordering a two-dimensional array relative to the main diagonal

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

Given a two-dimensional array *T* of size *NxN*, filled with various natural numbers (They do not have to be sorted in any way as in the example below.). My task is to write a program that transforms the array in such a way that all elements lying above the main diagonal are larger than each element lying on the diagonal and all elements lying below the main diagonal are to be smaller than each element on the diagonal.

For example:
*T* looks like this:
**[2,3,5]
[7,11,13]
[17,19,23]** 
 and one of the possible solutions is:
**[13,19,23]
[3,7,17]
[5,2,11]**

I have no clue how to do this. Would anyone have an idea what algorithm should be used here?

Comment: Wisblade's answer below is good, but another approach would be to use the fact that the middle `N` elements (out of all `N^2`) will make up your diagonal, so all you really need to do is quickselect the smallest diagonal element `e1` and the largest diagonal element `e2`. Next, you can populate your rearranged array by moving elements smaller than `e1` below the diagonal, elements between `e1` and `e2` on the diagonal, and elements larger than `e2` above the diagonal. This should be faster than sorting the entire array, given the nature of quickselect and that we run it twice.

Comment: @wLui155 True, but the "core problem" **IS** to find `e1` and `e2`, and it won't be simple... Because it means to find the median value, AND the `ceil(N/2)` values above AND the `floor(N/2)` values below. I don't know how to do that without sorting the array, at least partially...

Comment: If we adapt your notation of having an auxiliary array `vec` of size `N^2`, then `e1`, `e2` correspond to the `(N^2)/2 +- N/2`'th largest elements of `vec`, give or take. The intuition here is that we want a symmetric chunk around the midpoint. So, we cut `vec` in half, then traverse left and right to get a chunk of size `N`. I don't believe anything extra (like finding the median of `vec`) needs to be done to quickselect these particular boundary elements but do think figuring out these exact indices correctly, for even/odd cases of `N`, may be a little tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let's say the matrix is `NxN`.
- Put all `N²` values inside an array.
- Sort the array with whatever method you prefer (ascending order).
- In your final array, the `(N²-N)/2` first values go below the diagonal, the following `N` values go to the diagonal, and the final `(N²-N)/2` values go above the diagonal.

The following pseudo-code should do the job:

```
mat <- array[N][N] // To be initialized.
vec <- array[N*N]
for i : 0 to (N-1)
  for j : 0 to (N-1)
    vec[i*N+j]=mat[i][j]
  next j
next i
sort(vec)
p_below <- 0
p_diag <- (N*N-N)/2
p_above <- (N*N+N)/2

for i : 0 to (N-1)
  for j : 0 to (N-1)
    if (i>j)
      mat[i][j] = vec[p_above]
      p_above <- p_above + 1
    endif
    if (i<j)
      mat[i][j] = vec[p_below]
      p_below <- p_below + 1
    endif
    if (i=j)
      mat[i][j] = vec[p_diag]
      p_diag <- p_diag + 1
    endif
  next j
next i
```

Code can be **heavily** optimized by sorting directly the matrix, using a (quite complex) custom sort operator, so it can be sorted "in place". Technically, you'll do a bijection between the matrix indices to a partitioned set of indices representing "below diagonal", "diagonal" and "above diagonal" indices.

But I'm unsure that it can be considered as an algorithm in itself, because it will be highly dependent on the language used **AND** on how you stored, internally, your matrix (and how iterators/indices are used). I could write one in C++, but I lack knownledge to give you such an operator in Python.

Obviously, if you can't use a standard sorting function (because it can't work on anything else but an array), then you can write your own with the tricky comparison builtin the algorithm.

For such small matrixes, even a bubble-sort can work properly, but obviously implementing at least a quicksort would be better.

### Elements about optimizing:

First, we speak about the trivial bijection from matrix coordinate [x][y] to [i]: `i=x+y*N`. The invert is obviously `x=floor(i/N) & y=i mod N`. Then, you can parse the matrix as a vector.
This is already what I do in the first part initializing `vec`, BTW.

With matrix coordinates, it's easy:

- Diagonal is all cells where `x=y`.
- The "below" partition is everywhere `x<y`.
- The "above" partition is everywhere `x>y`.

Look at coordinates in the below 3x3 matrix, it's quite evident when you know it.

```
0,0  1,0  2,0
0,1  1,1  2,1
0,2  1,2  2,2
```

We already know that the ordered vector will be composed of three parts: first the "below" partition, then the "diagonal" partition, then the "above" partition.

The next bijection is way more tricky, since it requires either a piecewise linear function OR a look-up table. The first requires no additional memory but will use more CPU power, the second use as much memory as the matrix but will require less CPU power.
As always, optimization for speed often cost memory. If memory is scarse because you use huge matrixes, then you'll prefer a function.

In order to shorten a bit, I'll explain only for "below" partition. In the vector, the `(N-1)` first elements will be the ones belonging to the first column. Then, we'll have `(N-2)` elements for the 2nd column, `(N-3)` for the third, until we had only `1` element for the `(N-1)`th column. You see the scheme, sum of the number of elements and the column (zero-based index) is always `(N-1)`.

I won't write the function, because it's quite complex and, honestly, it won't help so much to understand. Simply know that converting from matrix indices to vector is "quite easy".

The opposite is more tricky and CPU-intensive, and it SHOULD use a `(N-1)` element vector to store where each column starts within the vector to GREATLY speed up the process. Thanks, this vector can also be used (from end to begin) for the "above" partition, so it won't burn too much memory.

Now, you can sort your "vector" normally, simply by chaining the two bijection together with the vector index, and you'll get a matrix cell instead. As long as the sorting algorithm is stable (that's usually the case), it will works and will sort your matrix "in place", at the expense of a lot of mathematical computing to "route" the linear indexes to matrix indexes.

Please note that, despite we speak about bijections, we need ONLY the "vector to matrix" formulas. The "matrix to vector" are important - it MUST be a bijection! - but you won't use them, since you'll sort directly the (virtual) vector from `0` to `N²-1`.

Comment: Could you show me how this bijection would work? The language doesn't matter anymore I am very curious about it because I want to do it optimally.

Comment: @PK96 I've added a paragraph to my answer. Honestly, it's more complicated to explain than to implement, because while implementing, you'll KNOW if you'll have a maximum matrix size, if they ALL have the same size, if you can (or not!) use more memory, etc. and so you'll find a solution that will be fast AND understandable by a code review.

Comment: As for this memory-consuming bijection, that is, if I understand correctly, I have to put into the *vec* array the elements from the lower triangle , then the diagonal and the higher triangle, and then we sort that?

Comment: Yes, that's it. And you can do this by using a look-up table, where you'll use a `N²` element vector containing the `(x,y)` position in the original matrix, so you won't need maths anymore - this can be filled directly with a simple double loop and three "pointers", in the way I did the reassignation at end of my initial pseudocode.